# div element does not collapses after setting its width to 0?

Tags: css

plzz inspect the snippet result

```html
<div style="border:1px solid black ; 
              height : 50px ;
              width:0 ; "></div>
```

after inspecting you will notice that the width of the element in the console is shown 0 . But if you see yourself div does not collapses, there is a little white space between left and right border .

My question is why is there a little white space between left and right borders after setting content width to 0 ? (note: I am not trying to achieve anything . I just want to have a better understanding of
CSS )

Comment: Perhaps for a collapse, height should be set to 0.

Comment: @GetSet . After your suggestion I kept height and width both equal to zero and still there is a strange white space inside div.

Comment: Pretty sure you have some CSS somewhere that's interfering. If you strip everything out and just use the following code (your div) you'll see nothing but a black dot on a red background. `<html><body style="background-color:red"><div style="border:1px solid black;height:0;width:0;"></div></body></html>`

Comment: @timgavin .  I run your code and still  there is a small red dot inside the div . The div is not  completely empty .   plzz help take away my misery timgavin .

Comment: @noob the border itself makes the div not completely empty. Remove the border too on "collapse"... If further issue arises, remove any inherent "margin" and "padding" on affected elements. ......... Collapse really should be a function of `display:none` where all issues of css is avoided

Comment: @noob The div is empty, as you can see in the code. If you run ONLY the code that I gave you you will not see a white dot, unless your browser is set up with some overriding CSS. If that's the case, try another browser.

Comment: @GetSet . Yes I get you getset but my question is why is the height and width of the content of the div is not 0 practically , why is there a tiny empty space inside the div  .  What I am expecting is a perfect black square  without any content space inside it .

Comment: Without knowing how your div is nested in the dom (structure) it is impossible to answer your question. You only show a snippet. .... That is you give no context as to how this div is nested in another. And you also give no css rules. @timgavin pointed out that there should be no issue if isolated. You still have a problem, therefore, you dont provide enough debugging details here.

Comment: @timgavin  . I run your code on mozilla firefox and I finally got a perfect black square . Thankyou timgavin but why the same code works differently on chrome and brave web browser .

Comment: @noob I ran it in Chrome and it's showing nothing but a single black pixel on a red background, which suggests that you have a setting in chrome that is overriding your css.

Comment: Perhaps a "cache" issue after changes have been made @timgavin and noob.

Comment: @GetSet Yep, just suggested that in my answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty sure you have some CSS somewhere that's interfering. If you strip everything out and just use the following code (your div) you'll see nothing but a black dot on a red background.

```html
<html><body style="background-color:red"><div style="border:1px solid black;height:0;width:0;"></div></body></html>
```

You mentioned in the comments that you're seeing a red space inside the div in Chrome, which suggests that you have a setting in Chrome that's causing this issue. Perhaps clearing your cache or resetting Chrome will resolve this?